# How to find specific string within a group of like-named elements

Tags: xslt, xslt-grouping

For the XML below, how would I find which Election, with the latest date if there are multiple elections elected, each employee has chosen. A default value of 'Bronze' would be used if all elections say 'Waive' or when there are no elections for that employee.

Example XML:

```
<Data>
    <Employee>
            <First_Name>Homer</First_Name>
            <Last_Name>Simpson</<Last_Name>
            <Elections>
                <Election type="Homer Simpson on 01/01/2020 (Gold Membership) (Waive)"/>
            </Elections>
            <Elections>
                <Election type="Homer Simpson on 01/01/2020 (Silver Membership) (Waive)"/>
            </Elections>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
            <First_Name>Marge</First_Name>
            <Last_Name>Simpson</<Last_Name>
            <Elections>
                <Election type="Marge Simpson on 01/01/2020 (Gold Membership) (Waive)"/>
            </Elections>
            <Elections>
                <Election type="Marge Simpson on 01/03/2020 (Gold Membership) (Elect)"/>
            </Elections>
            <Elections>
                <Election type="Marge Simpson on 01/03/2020 (Silver Membership) (Waive)"/>
            </Elections>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
            <First_Name>Lisa</First_Name>
            <Last_Name>Simpson</<Last_Name>
            <Elections>
                <Election type="Lisa Simpson on 01/01/2020 (Gold Membership) (Elect)"/>
            </Elections>
            <Elections>
                <Election type="Lisa Simpson on 01/01/2020 (Silver Membership) (Waive)"/>
            </Elections>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
            <First_Name>Bart</First_Name>
            <Last_Name>Simpson</<Last_Name>
            <Elections>
                <Election type="Bart Simpson on 01/01/2020 (Gold Membership) (Waive)"/>
            </Elections>
            <Elections>
                <Election type="Bart Simpson on 01/01/2020 (Silver Membership) (Waive)"/>
            </Elections>
            <Elections>
                <Election type="Bart Simpson on 01/01/2020 (Bronze Membership) (Elect)"/>
            </Elections>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
            <First_Name>Maggie</First_Name>
            <Last_Name>Simpson</<Last_Name>
            <Elections>
                <Election type="Lisa Simpson on 01/01/2020 (Silver Membership) (Elect)"/>
            </Elections>
            <Elections>
                <Election type="Lisa Simpson on 01/01/2020 (Gold Membership) (Waive)"/>
            </Elections>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
            <First_Name>Grandpa</First_Name>
            <Last_Name>Simpson</<Last_Name>
    </Employee>
</Data>
```

I tried a few things such as a for-each over the Elections/Election tag looking for the string "(Gold Membership) (Elect)" and "(Silver Membership) (Elect)" and setting a variable if it was found but that didn't work.

The desired output would be:
Homer, Simpson, Bronze
Marge, Simpson, Gold
Lisa, Simpson, Gold
Bart, Simpson, Bronze
Grandpa, Simpson, Silver

Comment: **1.** Does your processor support XSLT 2.0? **2.** What is the date format being used here? **3.** Why is the result for Grandpa Simpson Silver instead of the default Bronze?

Comment: 1. Yes the processor supports XSLT 2.0. 2. Date format is mm/dd/yyyy. 3. Grandpa should be Bronze. That was a mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a lot of work.

It would have been considerably simpler if each employee had only one election marked as `Elect`. But you say there can be more than one, and that only the latest one needs to be considered. And to make it even worse, you're using a date format that cannot be used for sorting as is.

Try something like the following:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/Data">
    <xsl:for-each select="Employee">
        <!-- names -->
        <xsl:value-of select="First_Name" /> 
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Last_Name" /> 
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text> 
        <!-- membership -->
        <xsl:variable name="valid-elections" select="Elections/Election[contains(@type, '(Elect)')]"/>      
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$valid-elections">
                <xsl:variable name="memberships" as="element()*">
                    <xsl:perform-sort>
                        <!-- sort by reformatted date -->
                        <xsl:sort select="replace(@type, '.*(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4}).*', '$3$1$2')" order="descending"/>
                        <xsl:sequence select="$valid-elections"/>
                    </xsl:perform-sort>
                </xsl:variable> 
                <!-- extract type from latest membership -->
                <xsl:value-of select="replace($memberships[1]/@type, '.*\((Gold|Silver|Bronze) Membership\).*', '$1')" /> 
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>Bronze</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWEaSvj